# Embedding .Net Runtime

Tags: c#, windows, mono, clr

Am I able to embed the .net runtime so that .net is not required on the host operating system? I was looking at doing this with Mono by looking here: http://mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono but seems to allude to using external modules to accomplish this.  My goal is to have one single executable with no installed .net runtime.  I do not know how this would be configured in my application to compile the native code, link the mono runtime- as well as compile the C# code and link that as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can now [statically compile Mono assemblies](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Nov-05.html) as was just demonstrated at PDC. The purpose of doing this was to allow .Net applications to run on the iPhone, but this should work anywhere.

There are some limitations to this; obviously, it can't depend on runtime-generated code, so Reflection.Emit is out.

Comment: Any more details on this such as a real example or other information?

Comment: This is a brand-new feature to 2.0.1, and doesn't yet support the 2.0 profile. There are no real examples yet that I am aware of, it's really more of a proof-of-concept than anything.

Answer (score 4):

Third-party solution i've used with much success: [Xenocode](http://www.xenocode.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported, and AFAIK there are no plans to change that status.

There are some third party tools out there that try to do this for you, but last time I checked none were very good yet.